# Installing OpenFaas on local Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, openfaas

so I'm attempting to install OpenFaaS on a local Kubernetes cluster made with Docker Desktop. I'm brand new to both OpenFaaS and Kubernetes so any help is appreciated!

I'm following the interactive tutorial [here](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/serverless/openfaas).

I have installed Helm, the OpenFaaS Cli, FaaS-netes, and followed everything in this tutorial up to page 4. On that page I am told to run this:

```
helm upgrade openfaas --install openfaas/openfaas --namespace openfaas --set functionNamespace=openfaas-fn --set operator.create=true --set basic_auth=true --set rbac=false --set faasIdler.dryRun=false --set faasIdler.inactivityDuration=10s
```

When I run that I get this error:

```
UPGRADE FAILED
Error: "openfaas" has no deployed releases
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "openfaas" has no deployed releases
```

I'm really lost at what I am supposed to do here. Did I miss a step in the tutorial? How do I deploy a release?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Does `helm list` include an `openfaas` entry?  Does `helm del --purge` clear things up?

Comment: @DavidMaze I deleted the openfaas helm entry and recreated and it solved the problem! I thought that it would be something simple and stupid. Thanks!

Comment: @BananaPineapple If You found a solution, could You please add answer to Your question and accept it, so if someone from community had same issue, he will find answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, delete the openfaas entry from helm using helm del —purge and try remaking it. Everything worked the second try.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the Chart with arkade (fastest option)

The arkade install command installs OpenFaaS using its official helm chart, but without using tiller, a component which is insecure by default. arkade can also install other important software for OpenFaaS users such as cert-manager and nginx-ingress. It's the easiest and quickest way to get up and running.

You can use arkade to install OpenFaaS to a regular cloud cluster, your laptop, a VM, a Raspberry Pi, or a 64-bit ARM machine.

```
# For MacOS / Linux:
curl -SLsf https://dl.get-arkade.dev/ | sudo sh

# For Windows (using Git Bash)
curl -SLsf https://dl.get-arkade.dev/ | sh
```

Install the OpenFaaS app
If you're using a managed cloud Kubernetes service which supplies LoadBalancers, then run the following:

```
arkade install openfaas --load-balancer
```

Note: the `--load-balancer` flag has a default of false, so by passing the flag, the installation will request one from your cloud provider.

If you're using a local Kubernetes cluster or a VM, then run:

```
arkade install openfaas
```

After the installation you'll receive a command to retrieve your OpenFaaS URL and password.

Other options for installation are available with arkade install openfaas --help

For cloud users run kubectl get -n openfaas svc/gateway-external and look for EXTERNAL-IP. This is your gateway address.